# Removing searchresult from other languages in expression engine

Tags: expressionengine

I want to remove search result that is not pointing to the current language code.

I have expression engine 2.5.3 and using the Multi language 2.0 module and the built-in search engine.

This will remove those results but will mess up the pagination.( Some page got 1 result, another has 10 results... )

```
{exp:search:search_results}
    <?php if(get_langcode_from_url('{page_uri}') == "{country_code}"){?>
        <div>{title}</div>
    <?php } ?>
{/exp:search:search_results}
```

Is there a better solution to this? I prefer not to buy any modules if it's unnecessary.

Comment: Is this something Super Search module fixes?
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/super-search

Answer (score 0):

Was hoping someone would have a better answer for this but as no one has answered...

Approaches to this solution I'd consider:

1. Roll your own pagination.
2. Somehow get your results limited at a higher level so native pagination would work. There is a thread about this in [the module's support forum](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/multi-language-module/viewthread/2769).
3. Disguise your pagination issues by loading them a little differently.  Maybe something like [Infinite Scroll](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/infinite-scroll) could help?  Not free but not too dear either.

If you've arrived at your own solution by now I'd love to hear it.  Multi-language support is the next big thing on the to do list for us.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My solution was to use the code i wrote above and remove pagination. And limit the searchresult to 100 items. Let's face it you never look at more then 40 results anyway. It is not the most beautifull solution but it will work in my situation. I'm sorry to say that EE seams lite to inflexible to work with compare to the opensource frameworks I'm used to. Like django and so on.